# javascript: receive radio button value in a radio group and command different instruction according to each case

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp

I want to store new row in a database table when a person checked a first radio button in a radio group. Inserting database row is ok. But I don't know a below part among the whole codes.

```
if(document.form1.RadioGroup1_0.checked){

}
```

Eclipse says **"document cannot be resolved to a variable"** and there is a red underline at **"document"**. I don't know how to make it work. Please help me!

test.jsp ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
   <section>   
  <h2></h2>
  <p><img src="css/images/q1.JPG" width="552" height="183" alt=""/></p>
  <p>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="radio" id="RadioGroup1_0">
      1</label>
    <br>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="radio" id="RadioGroup1_1">
      2</label>
    <br>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="radio" id="RadioGroup1_2">
      3</label>
    <br>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="radio" id="RadioGroup1_3">
      4</label>
    <br>
  </p>
  <p></p>
 </section>

<input type="button" name="btnsubmit" value="submit" style="width:170px;height:35px;margin-  
 left:390px;margin-bottom:20px" onClick="window.location.href='result.jsp'">
```

result.jsp //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
<%@page import="jsp.*,java.sql.*" %>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=EUC-KR"
    pageEncoding="EUC-KR"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01      
Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<%  

if(document.form1.RadioGroup1_0.checked){

}
%>
```

Answer (score 2):

`document.form1.RadioGroup1_0.checked` is javascript code and you are writing inside scripplets